# R shiny: insertUI and observeEvent in module

Tags: r, shiny

Using the `diamonds` dataset as an example, after a button is pressed, two pickerInput should appear.
In the first one, the user chooses between three columns of the `diamonds` dataset. Once a value is selected the app should update the choices of the second pickertInput based on the unique values of the selected column.

The app works well without modularizing it. After reading couple of discussions about modules, I still don't clearly understand how to properly declare reactive values for accessing the different `input$...`.

**MODULE**

```
module.UI <- function(id){
    ns <- NS(id)
    
    actionButton(inputId = ns("add"), label = "Add")
}

module <- function(input, output, session, data, variables){
    ns <- session$ns
    
    observeEvent(input$add, {
        insertUI(
            selector = "#add",
            where = "beforeBegin",
            ui = fluidRow(
                pickerInput(inputId = "picker_variable",
                            choices = variables,
                            selected = NULL
                ),
                pickerInput(inputId = "picker_value",
                            choices = NULL,
                            selected = NULL
                )
            )
        )
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$picker_variable,{
        updatePickerInput(session,
                          inputId = "picker_value",
                          choices = as.character(unlist(unique(data[, input$picker_variable]))),
                          selected = NULL
        )
    })
}
```

**APP**

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    mainPanel(
        module.UI(id = "myID")
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    callModule(module = module, id = "myID", data = diamonds, variables=c("cut", "color", "clarity"))
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**EDIT**
User should be able to click the button more than once in order to create several `pickerInput` pairs.

**EDIT #2**
Based on @starja code, trying to return the values of the 2 pickers leads to a NULL object.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(ggplot2)

module.UI <- function(id, variables){
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  ui = fluidRow(
    pickerInput(inputId = ns("picker_variable"),
                choices = variables,
                selected = NULL
    ),
    pickerInput(inputId = ns("picker_value"),
                choices = NULL,
                selected = NULL
    )
  )
}

module <- function(input, output, session, data, variables){
  module_out <- reactiveValues(variable=NULL, values=NULL)

  observeEvent(input$picker_variable,{
    updatePickerInput(session,
                      inputId = "picker_value",
                      choices = as.character(unlist(unique(data[, input$picker_variable]))),
                      selected = NULL
    )
  })
  
  observe({
    module_out$variable <- input$picker_variable
    module_out$values <- input$picker_value
  })

  return(module_out)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    actionButton(inputId = "add",
                 label = "Add"),
    tags$div(id = "add_UI_here")
  )
)

list_modules <- list()
current_id <- 1

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$add, {
    
    new_id <- paste0("module_", current_id)
    
    list_modules[[new_id]] <<-
      callModule(module = module, id = new_id,
                 data = diamonds, variables = c("cut", "color", "clarity"))
    
    insertUI(selector = "#add_UI_here",
             ui = module.UI(new_id, variables = c("cut", "color", "clarity")))
    
    current_id <<- current_id + 1
    
  })

  req(input$list_modules)
  print(list_modules)
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**EDIT #3**
Still having difficulties to return the values of the 2 pickers in a list that would be convenient to access further (example below):

```
module_out
$module_1
$module_1$variable
[1] "cut"

$module_1$values
[1] "Ideal"   "Good"

$module_2
$module_2$variable
[1] "color"

$module_2$values
[1] "E"   "J"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has 2 issues:

- if you insert UI elements in a module via `insertUI`, the ids of the UI elements need to have the correct namespace: `ns(id)`
- because the id you use in the `selector` of `insertUI` was created in the module, it is also namespaced, so the `selector` argument also has to be namespaced

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(ggplot2)

module.UI <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  actionButton(inputId = ns("add"), label = "Add")
}

module <- function(input, output, session, data, variables){
  ns <- session$ns
  
  observeEvent(input$add, {
    insertUI(
      selector = paste0("#", ns("add")),
      where = "beforeBegin",
      ui = fluidRow(
        pickerInput(inputId = ns("picker_variable"),
                    choices = variables,
                    selected = NULL
        ),
        pickerInput(inputId = ns("picker_value"),
                    choices = NULL,
                    selected = NULL
        )
      )
    )
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$picker_variable,{
    updatePickerInput(session,
                      inputId = "picker_value",
                      choices = as.character(unlist(unique(data[, input$picker_variable]))),
                      selected = NULL
    )
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    module.UI(id = "myID")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  callModule(module = module, id = "myID", data = diamonds, variables=c("cut", "color", "clarity"))
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

BTW: I feel that a more natural way to modularise your code would be that the `Add` button is in the main app and then dynamically inserts an instance of your module, so that your module only contains the logic/UI for one combination `picker_variable`/`picker_value`

---

### Edit

Thanks for your remark. In fact, it doesn't make much sense to create several `pickerInput` in the module with the same `inputId`. I've changed my code to reflect the pattern that the `actionButton` is in the main app and every module only contains one set of inputs:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(ggplot2)

module.UI <- function(id, variables){
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  ui = fluidRow(
    pickerInput(inputId = ns("picker_variable"),
                choices = variables,
                selected = NULL
    ),
    pickerInput(inputId = ns("picker_value"),
                choices = NULL,
                selected = NULL
    )
  )
}

module <- function(input, output, session, data, variables){
  
  observeEvent(input$picker_variable,{
    updatePickerInput(session,
                      inputId = "picker_value",
                      choices = as.character(unlist(unique(data[, input$picker_variable]))),
                      selected = NULL
    )
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    actionButton(inputId = "add",
                 label = "Add"),
    tags$div(id = "add_UI_here")
  )
)

list_modules <- list()
current_id <- 1

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$add, {
    
    new_id <- paste0("module_", current_id)
    
    list_modules[[new_id]] <<-
      callModule(module = module, id = new_id,
                 data = diamonds, variables = c("cut", "color", "clarity"))
    
    insertUI(selector = "#add_UI_here",
             ui = module.UI(new_id, variables = c("cut", "color", "clarity")))
    
    current_id <<- current_id + 1
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

### Edit 2

You can directly return the `input` from the module and use this in a reactive context in the main app:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(ggplot2)

module.UI <- function(id, variables){
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  ui = fluidRow(
    pickerInput(inputId = ns("picker_variable"),
                choices = variables,
                selected = NULL
    ),
    pickerInput(inputId = ns("picker_value"),
                choices = NULL,
                selected = NULL
    )
  )
}

module <- function(input, output, session, data, variables){
  
  observeEvent(input$picker_variable,{
    updatePickerInput(session,
                      inputId = "picker_value",
                      choices = as.character(unlist(unique(data[, input$picker_variable]))),
                      selected = NULL
    )
  })
  
  return(input)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    actionButton(inputId = "print", label = "print inputs"),
    actionButton(inputId = "add",
                 label = "Add"),
    tags$div(id = "add_UI_here")
  )
)

list_modules <- list()
current_id <- 1

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$add, {
    
    new_id <- paste0("module_", current_id)
    
    list_modules[[new_id]] <<-
      callModule(module = module, id = new_id,
                 data = diamonds, variables = c("cut", "color", "clarity"))
    
    insertUI(selector = "#add_UI_here",
             ui = module.UI(new_id, variables = c("cut", "color", "clarity")))
    
    current_id <<- current_id + 1
    
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$print, {
    lapply(seq_len(length(list_modules)), function(i) {
      print(names(list_modules)[i])
      print(list_modules[[i]]$picker_variable)
      print(list_modules[[i]]$picker_value)
    })
  })
  
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation ! If I understand correctly, the take-home message would be: (1) all `inputId` created in a module have to be namespaced, (2) once created, we do not need to namespace the inputId we are calling within the module (e.g. the events in `observeEvent` and the `inputId` in the `updatePickerInput`). Is tit correct?

Comment: Exactly. If you want to access an inputId within a module, the module cares about the correct namespace, only for creating a new Id you have to make sure it is the correct namespace.

Comment: Got it ! Thank you very much.

Comment: Actually, the code partially works. The first time we press the "Add" button, everything works well, but if we press it a second time no values are displayed in the second `pickerInput`.

Comment: Brilliant ! However, for subsetting my data table, trying to return `picker_variable` and `picker_value` using `list_modules[[new_id]]` leads to nothing (see my **EDIT #2**).

Comment: @u31889 you can directly return the `input` from the module. I'm not sure if you can use the returned reactive values without a reactive context, so I added an action button to print the values

Comment: Thanks. I tried the same also but it returns the function, not the values. And when I try in the module `return(list(variable=reactive({input$picker_variable}), value=reactive({input$picker_value})))` or simply `return(variable=input$picker_variable, value=input$picker_value)`, the list elements are NULL.

Comment: @u31889 I sometimes also have problems with the return values of modules. Can you show what you try to achieve with the returned values/how you print them? Because the return values are reactive values, you can only use them in a reactive context. Does the code from my second edit works for you?

Comment: Yes, values returned by modules remain obscure to me. It seems to be difficult to print what the module returns (for debugging purpose). What would be convenient to get is in my **EDIT #3**.

Comment: I updated my **Edit 2** so that you have a pretty print of the variables